spring-boot: setting logging level in application.yml has no effect
We have existing application.yml in our src/main/resources dir, and I added:
logging:
  level:
    ROOT: TRACE

Because we get tens of thousands of DEBUG lines when we start the app, its impossible to see errors.
However, when we set the level to TRACE, it still show all DEBUG lines, it doesnt seem to have any effect.  We have nothing on the startup command line which overrides this.
WE are running it in intellij.  Not sure if that makes any difference.
Any ideas what could be blocking log level config?
We are using the standard spring-boot logback.
Not sure what version of spring boot we are using, but its old (not 3) with java 8.
in our logback.xml file, where we set the pattern, we also have this:
<root level="debug">
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
</root>

No idea what the level="debug" does in this code, or if its overriding the ROOT:TRACE directive, but I tried this:
<root>
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
</root>

But we still get DEBUG logs for everything.

That is, to begin with, because a log level of trace logs everything; it logs MORE than debug.
TRACE - DEBUG - INFO - WARN - ERROR
The more to the left you go, the more you will see. Set the log level in your application.yaml to info if you want to hide debug and trace logging. Set the loglevel to warn or error if you also want to hide info logging.
The level="debug" on the logback root logger defines the default level for log appenders that are attached to it. So in the snippet that is posted, you will effectively never see trace logs in STDOUT until you change the default level to be trace.
https://logback.qos.ch/manual/configuration.html
The trick is to be as picky as you can be though; globally setting the root loglevel to be at info level for example will have the side effect of throwing away all debug logging AFTER startup you may still want to see. So my recommendation would be to see in the log output which specific top level packages are responsible for generating that logging, and then configuring the log levels for those packages specifically. So if you use Hibernate for example which is prone to log a lot of repetitive noise on startup, you could filter out anything but errors for Hibernate by putting this in your application.yml:
logging:
  level:
    org.hibernate: ERROR

rinse and repeat for all other shouty packages.

Yep, I realized my mistake too - trace is below debug. slaps forehead
